# Can't get the html generated report using dependency-check-sonar-plugin

Tags: windows, sonarqube, maven-dependency-check-plugin

I'm trying to generate an html report to identify vulnerabilities in a project 'Angularjs & php' using dependency-check-sonar-plugin & sonarqube in Windows os on local sonar server. After running this command :

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=my-project-api -Dsonar.sources=. - 
Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/ -Dsonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath=dependency-check- 
report.html
```

I still can't see the report and got this message : "No HTML-Report found. Please check property sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath"
did i miss something ?
here my configuration file :

```
sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath=dependency-check-report.html
sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath=ependency-check-report.html

sonar.dependencyCheck.severity.blocker=9.0
sonar.dependencyCheck.severity.critical=7.0
sonar.dependencyCheck.severity.major=4.0
sonar.dependencyCheck.severity.minor=0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Your config says:

```
sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath=ependency-check-report.html
```

There is a 'd' missing-